why this error is occurred in tablet. "user cancel scrollshot " onStop() method of activity
`I am using camera to detect the face. when i m trying to back then in application its crashing and throws above error. Even I haven't written a code of onstop method. and even not using scrollview or any other scrollable view. And this error is only getting in Tablet. Working fine in mobile. I m trying to switch front and back camera and then onstop method is crashes
user cancel scrollshot
java.lang.Throwable
at android.util.screenscrollshot.ScrollableViewRECUtil.cancel(ScrollableViewRECUtil.java:287)
android.app.Activity.onScrollScreenshotCancel(Activity.java:972)
at android.app.Activity.onStop(Activity.java:2505)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStop(FragmentActivity.java:520)

at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop(AppCompatActivity.java:257)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1473)
at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:8089)
at android.app.ActivityThread.callActivityOnStop(ActivityThread.java:4648)
android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:4626)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:4701)
\>!                  your textandroid.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:233)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:13               android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
android.app`
